# Android - executing different functions with multiple threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, timer

I am pretty new to Android programming but got some experience in other languages. I want to create an APP which is principle working like this.

[image]

1. The APP is a process which is asking my Web-/Database-Server every 10 seconds if there is an event to execute.
2. The Web-/Database-Server answers with an event id or even a function name.
3. The APP opens a new thread which executes the event with the id or even better directly the function name.

My Questions are:

1. Is this perfomant? Or can this chrash pretty easily?
2. Is it limited to 2 threads within the process or can I even open every time a new thread for the function which I want to execute? Maybe because of the other function is still running?
3. How can I execute a function with the return value? For example

   `InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
    //Get the data in the entity`

   `public in(void)
    {
    // execute a function which got´s the same name as the variable "in"
    }`

The result should be: The one thread is asking every 10 seconds my Web-/Database-Server if there is an event. The event gets executed within a thread and this is working parallel (at the same time without crashing or even getting stucked).

Sample Code of these Threads would be appreciated.

My code till yet:

> public class service extends Service {
>       private static final String TAG = "MyService";
>
> ```
> @Override
> public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
> {
>     return null;
> }
>
> public void onDestroy() 
> {
>     Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>     Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
> }
>
> @Override
> public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startid)
> {
>
>     Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>     Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
>
>     Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
>     {
>       @Override
>       public void run()
>       {
>          new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() 
>          {
>           @Override
>             public void run() 
>           {
>                      System.out.println("Send GO!");
>                      Device dev = new Device();
>
>                      dev.getDeviceId(getBaseContext());
>                      dev.getEmail(getBaseContext());
>
>                      dev.sendDeviceItems();
>                    }
>                }, 0, 10000);//put here time 1000 milliseconds=1 second
>           }
>           });
>
>     thread.start();   
>     return Service.START_STICKY;
>    } }
> ```

Comment: Polling (every 10 seconds) is not a good solution because your app won't be able to run disconnected from the server.  You should revist your requirements and possibly a port solution that the server can ping when it has a new message for your app to process.  Side note:  I invented the word performant!  I've been using it for years.

Comment: Also a nice solution. I was also thinking of this but is it possible that the phone if it won´t receive a message within a time range, get´s into a kind of sleep mode? And if the phone is permanent listening, is this really effective or also a waste of battery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Is this perfomant? Or can this chrash pretty easily?

   - Yes it will be performance hit. Asking for api every 10sec will drain your battery also.
   - With proper exception handling it won't crash pretty easily.

Is it limited to 2 threads within the process or can I even open every time a new thread for the function which I want to execute? Maybe because of the other function is still running?

- You can run as many threads you want but it will be difficult to maintain code in that
   case . You can use VOLLY or OKHTTP for network related things they will handle you thread
   part also.

How can I execute a function with the return value? For example

InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
 //Get the data in the entity

public in(void)
 {
 // execute a function which got´s the same name as the variable "in"
 }

- For calling method at run time with Method name you can just use of REFLECTION in java. This will fulfil your need.

Comment: Hey Suhail Mehta! Thanks a lot for this explanation! :) I will try to get through this stuff you posted :) really thanks! :) Other tips or even hints are of course still appreciated!

Comment: Found many usefull things within this post, especially volley.